# JSON url Redirection fails

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, redirect

I've JSON parsing Asynchronous task, When I use URL http://example.com/json/note.json  it is working (Using free JSON hosting service, I can't edit after saving). But my file is not placed permanently on one link. So I've Redirecting new JSON URL using URL redirection service. When I use my URL redirection service, my URL doesn't redirects to http://example.com/json/new_note.json.

```
new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://example.com/json/note.json"); //works

new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://example.com/redirection_service_url"); //doesn't works
```

**JSONAsyncTask**

```
class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                 StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("array");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        jsono = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects

                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);

                    }

                    return true;
                } else {


                    Log.e("Error", "Something went wrong");
                }


                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

      if (result == false) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to Fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

Using my URL redirection service URL in browsers shows my JSON data, I ensured it has  no errors.

Please help!

Comment: Can you please publish your JSONAsyncTask code

Comment: AsyncTask class is added

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Android doesn't support redirecting on HTTP connections even when the method is GET.

You should take your HTTP response and extract the Location header and then make another request for the JSON payload.